# Edges of Youtube video embed being cut off on small screen size

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am building a site with Next.js and tailwind.

I am struggling to get the video component to display correctly on a mobile screen size.

I have tried multiple ways to fix the issue – but the sides of the video are still being cut off on a smaller screen size.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue please?

The deployed site can be viewed at:
[www.catrinmentzoni.com](http://www.catrinmentzoni.com)

And the Github repo at: https://github.com/Babyoilrig/Catrin--Mentzoni-Portfolio

Thanks very much

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with the responsive youtube embed hack,  here is the fixed solution via codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-parm-mmj5xw?file=/components/VideoSection/index.js:1114-1251

You can see the solve here - https://mmj5xw.sse.codesandbox.io/

```
  <div
    class="grid gap-0 grid-cols-1 
    grid-rows-1 place-items-center
 content-center pl-5 pr-5" // <<< This is not needed.
    className={css.videoResponsive}
```

In here the `className={css.videoResponsive}` was not applying, you can remove the tailwind classes `class=grid gap-0` etc. as the youtube video responsive positioning code takes care of filling the page.

In general `class` works as of React 16 but it throws a warning which you can see in your console as well, I would pick `className` consistently while writing JSX

I also removed the width/height from the iframe.

## Update

It looks like the additional ask is for Desktop to be 50% and centered and mobile to be full width.

Use the below as direction and not a fix.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .videoResponsive {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .videoResponsive::after {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .videoResponsive iframe,
  .videoResponsive object,
  .videoResponsive embed {
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 915px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .videoResponsive {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .videoResponsive::after {
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    display: block;
    content: "";
  }
  .videoResponsive iframe,
  .videoResponsive object,
  .videoResponsive embed {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

You can use media queries to change behavior, however in trying to be responsive, the `padding-top` adds additional space, which you should try to play around and fix.

The codesandbox above is updated to show the result https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-parm-mmj5xw?file=/components/VideoSection/VideoSection.module.css:680-1556

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - I can get it so the video fills the page on both the web and mobile version - but I didn't want it to fill the screen on web - I only wanted it at about 50% of the width (centred) and fullscreen on mobile. Any ideas how I could do this please? Thanks

Comment: See updated answer, its incomplete but you can use it as a start - If this or another answer helped you solve your issue, Please mark it as accepted.